I am making desktop app which runs python script in flutter.python script run perfectly in debug mode but not in release mode
I am trying to make monitoring system like time tracker in flutter desktop app.In which i write python script to run that it works perfectly in debug but script is not running in release mode.
I tried  it is not working did any one has solutions.

Have you added a internet permission in androidmanifest.xml ?

I added that but it only run python script which is inside my app asseet.its working on debug but python script not runing on desktop.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

do you have the necessary Python runtime environment bundled with your release build?
if not...you can use tools like pyinstaller

install it using pip pip install pyinstaller
with the terminal navigate to the flutter project and run this command pyinstaller --onefile main.py (ofc change main.py by the actual file name)
this will create an EXE file it will include the python libraries and the venv

hope it helps.
